# PHPUnit - breaking code into testable chunks

Tags: php, tdd, phpunit

I read somewhere that it's a good idea to break methods down into smaller, testable functions so that the smaller methods can be tested. But I'm confused on how to test the method that calls the smaller method. Here's an example:

```php
class MyTestableClass
{
    public function myHugeFunction($list, array $list_filter_params)
    {
        // do a bunch of stuff, then...
        foreach($list as $item) {
            $this->subFunction($item);
        }
    }

    public function subFunction()
    {
        // do stuff for each item
    }
}
```

and the test class:

```php
class MyTestableClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testSubFunction
    {
        // This tests the smaller, bite-size method, which is good.
    }
    public function testMyHugeFunction
    {
        // this tests the parent function *and* the subFunction. I'm trying
        // to test *just* the parent function.
    }
}
```

I know how to test the subFunction, but since I can't stub a method in the same class, I don't know how to test the parent method *only*. I'd like to find a way of somehow stubbing the subFunction to just return true.

Do you use Events and stub the event class? That's the only way I can think of to stub another method called in the same class.

Comment: Is `MyClass` the class being tested or the test itself?

Comment: @WaleedKhan MyClass is the class being tested, I'll edit the example for clarification.

Comment: I can't say for sure because you did not provide a *real example*, but it looks like you misunderstood something. Is `subFunction` really part of the public interface? If not, you should not test it separately. Breaking down your software into testable parts is also about decoupling, but it looks like you still have a huge tightly coupled class instead of multiple concise testable *units*.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how I would decouple this. Is this right? Instead of calling ```myHugeFunction``` and checking for success, I would have ```myHugeFunction``` just return the the list, and for each list item run ```subFunction```.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from things what @fab said in his comment (which you really should consider!), actually you can stub / mock methods in the SUT. For your example, build your SUT object may looks like:

```
class MyTestableClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testSubFunction
    {
        // This tests the smaller, bite-size method, which is good.
    }
    public function testMyHugeFunction
    {
        // first, prepare your arugments $list and $list_filter_params
        // (...)

        // Next build mock. The second argument means that you will mock ONLY subFunction method
        $this->sut = $this->getMock('Namespace\MyTestableClass', array('subFunction'));

        // now you can set your subFunction expectations:
        $this->sut->expects($this->exactly(count($list))
            ->with($this->anything()); // of course you can make this mock better, I'm just showing a case

        // start testing
        $this->sut->myHugeFunction($list, $list_filter_params);
    }
}
```

PS And again, as @fab said: if you show a specific case, I'm sure you'll get a lot of good answers from people here.

Comment: +1 because it's a more consise version of what I would have written. As an addition though, there are cases where it's very hard to get rid of dependencies and mocking doesn't solve the problem; in these cases, I've found that [Patchwork](https://github.com/antecedent/patchwork/) can be helpful to explicitly override a method.